# Can't detect when post requests finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am submitting multiple data multiple times on one button click.

First I submit data to a variable number of hidden iframes **(the form is `enctype="multipart/form-data"`)**. Then I would like to run the normal submit button/function which redirects the main page.

If i do this all in one function though, I don't end up recieving all the data I send to the hidden iframes. I believe the redirect begins before the other forms finish sending (sometimes I receive the first data submitted, most of the time I receive none).

I have hacked a solution using `setTimeout(function(){$("#submitbtn").click()},3000)`... but clearly this won't always take 3 seconds. I want a way of detecting when it finishes so I can start the submit.

Sorry if this is hard to understand, if you need more info just comment/ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using the IFRAME.load, to detect changes to the target iframes. Once all iframes.load()'s fired I fired the last submit (the one that redirects the main page).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are submitting that data to the iframes but if you are using `$.ajax` you can set `async : false` which will pause every jQuery event, animation, etc. There may be something similiar if you are using a different method.

Comment: I have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so I don't believe I can use `$.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX I recommend using the *success* callback of jQuery's $.post.

e.g.

```
$.post('/process', form_data, function(data) { document.location = '/thankyou'; false})
```

In this example after the post data has been successfully submitted the user will be redirected to /thankyhou

You can also use $("#submitbtn").click() in the callback.

Comment: please teach me how i can use ajax with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and i'll give you the correct answer